# SIGABRT When using AVFoundation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, avfoundation

I took this code from an app we made and which is already in store (and still running without issues).
But when I try to run it in a new app, I get a SIGABRT.

Here´s a sample class which I used to reproduced the crash in Xamarin.Forms via DependencyService. The error property remains null after creating the recorder.

```
public class RedordDependencies : IRecordDependencies
{
    NSObject[] values = new NSObject[] {
        NSNumber.FromFloat (44100.0f), //Sample Rate
        NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int)AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.LinearPCM), //AVFormat
        NSNumber.FromInt32 (2), //Channels
        NSNumber.FromInt32 (16), //PCMBitDepth
        NSNumber.FromBoolean (false), //IsBigEndianKey
        NSNumber.FromBoolean (false) //IsFloatKey
    };

    NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[] {
        AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
        AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
        AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
        AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
        AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey
    };

    AVAudioRecorder recorder;
    NSError error;
    NSDictionary settings;

    public RedordDep()
    {
        settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);
    }

    public string Prepare()
    {
        NSUrl path = NSUrl.FromString(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".wav"));
        recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(path, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);
        bool prepared = recorder.PrepareToRecord();
        return path.Path;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I found out that this also happens in other cases when using AVFoundation.
In my case it happened when I tried to initialize a video recorder and audio recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this
[Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/SYNTaXx89/86c8ac9ea54d392d565f405f69f8fed7)
I found out that it is related to the security options that are introduced to iOS 10. I just had to add Usage Description Keys I needed.
"NSCameraUsageDescription" and "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription"